# C arrays and loops

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I got an assigment from school to calculate some stuff, but when I run the program nothing shows up, can anyone figure out what's wrong with this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int arr[]= {3,6,18,12,15,30,60,70,11,10};
    int rt,i,x;

    for (i = 0;i >= 10; i++)
        rt += arr[i];

    for (x = 0;x >= 10; x++)
    {
        printf("The value of resistor at location %d is %d\n",i,arr[i]);
        printf("The value of the RT is %d\n",rt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Another one: the loop uses `for (x = 0;x >= 10; x++)` but printf uses `i` - `printf("The value of resistor at location %d is %d\n",i,arr[i]);`

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop conditions to exit the loop are wrong.  Specifically, `i` should be `< 10` not `>= 10`.  When `i = 0`, the loop immediately terminates because it isn't `>= 10`.  As such, you need to modify your code so that it's `< 10`.  The reason why is because `C` starts at index `0` when referencing an array, and you have 10 elements in your array.  Also, `rt` looks like an accumulator variable, and so you'll also need to set this to `0` before looping.

Another small but fundamental bug in your code is the second `for` loop.  Specifically, your increment variable is `x`, but you are using `i` within the `for` loop.  As such, either change the variables within the `for` loop to `x`, or change the loop index so that it is `i` and not `x`.  I did the former.

Another small suggestion I have is to place the `printf` statement that displays the `rt` variable outside of the `for` loop.  This variable never changes during each iteration, and so it is safe to assume that you only want to display it once.

As such:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
  int arr[]= {3,6,18,12,15,30,60,70,11,10};
  int rt,i,x;
  rt = 0; // As you are accumulating values
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    rt += arr[i];

  for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
     printf("The value of resistor at location %d is %d\n",x,arr[x]);

  printf("The value of the RT is %d\n",rt);
}
```

Comment: He is also using the wrong index variable in the second loop. `i` and `arr[i]` should be `x` and `arr[x]`.

Comment: @SimpleJ: Nice spot. I missed that one.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
for (x = 0;x >= 10; x++)
```

should be

```
for (x = 0;x < 10; x++)
```

otherwise it will never execute since first x is assigned zero, then you check if x >= 10.

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat? Your for loop condition is not correct, it's backwards.

```
 for (i = 0;i >= 10; i++)
```

should be:

```
 for (i = 0;i < 10; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop should be testing x<= 10.

Comment: The array only has 10 elements so you have an off-by-one error in your loop condition.